# Colorability classes of graphs

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, graph-colorings

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a simple, undirected graph, finite or infinite, with $V \neq \emptyset$. We consider the chromatic number $\chi(G)$ as a *cardinal*. We say that [colorings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring) $c:V\to \chi(G)$ are *proper* colorings and we denote the set of proper colorings of $G$ by $\text{PCol}(G)$.

If $c\in\text{PCol}(G)$ we denote the *set of fibers* of $c$ by $\text{Fib}(c) = \big\{c^{-1}
(\{k\}): k\in \chi(G)\big\}$.

**Colorability class 1:** We say that $G$ is of colorability class 1 if $\text{Fib}(c) = \text{Fib}(c')$ for all $c,c'\in \text{PCol}(G)$. Examples for this class include the complete graphs and the complete bipartite graphs.

**Colorability class 2:** $G$ is in this class if it is not in Class 1, but $\text{Fib}(c) \cap \text{Fib}(c') \neq \emptyset$ for all $c, c'\in \text{PCol}(G)$.

**Colorability class 3:** $G$ is in this class if it is not in classes 1 or 2.

An "exotic" subspecies of class 3 is described below. First we need this notion:
If $X\neq \emptyset$ consists of sets, let $\text{cards}(X) = \{|x|: x\in X\}$.

**Colorability class 3a:** $G$ is in class 3a if there are colorings $c, c'\in \text{PCol}(G)$ such that $$\text{cards}\big(\text{Fib}(c)\big) \cap \text{cards}\big(\text{Fib}(c')\big) = \emptyset.$$ An interesting example of this is the circular graph $C_9$: consider the colorings 0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2 vs 0,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2.

Many more of these classes can be formed in a natural way using the notion of $\text{Fib}(c)$ and constructions similar to the ones defined above.

**Questions.** Have these, or similar, classes been studied somewhere? And is there an example of a graph of Colorability class 2?

Comment: Isn't Colorability Class 1 the same as the [uniquely colorable graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniquely_colorable_graph)?

Comment: Isn't the [butterfly graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_graph) in colorability class 2?

Comment: I think the smallest example of a graph in colorability class 2 is $K_3\cup K_1$.

Comment: Thanks @bof for the correct term of unique colorability, and yes, $K_3 \cup K_1$ does work.